# Using HDMI from Nvidia card to Samsung monitor with Ubuntu 11.10, and desktop needs zooming out. Any ideas how?

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi, zoom

In windows 7 (maybe it was the nvidia control panel), I can zoom the display out (maybe it was I set the size to 90% or something), but on Ubuntu, I can't find any setting to do this.  I do have the nvidia drivers installed.  This causes the outer 1/2" of screen to be cut off.  My monitor does not have a setting to fix this as many TV's do.

Any secret setting that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but on my Nvida X Server Settings application (installed under the `Additional Drivers` application), under the GPU section (may be a bit different for you depending on your hardware) I have an `Overscan Compensation` slider that will do what you are after.